# Is there a non-recursive solution to get a list of all possible concatenations of array of strings?

Tags: java, concatenation

I receive as an input an array of strings.
I have to create a list of strings that are a concatenation of all the strings of the input array, appearing once and only once for each string.
For example if the input array is `["aa","bb","cc"]` the resulting list of strings will be `"aabbcc",aaccbb","bbaacc","bbccaa",ccaabb","ccbbaa"`
The length of the input array is not known, it can be any number.
The length of all the substrings in the array is the same.
I see this [Java: get all concatenations of List<List<String>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110174/java-get-all-concatenations-of-listliststring) question.
But are there any non-recursive solution for this?

Comment: Any solution that can be written with recursion can be written without. If you know of a recursive solution, you can adapt it to use an imperative loop by adding a `Stack` object to emulate the call stack that recursion makes use of. It might not (actually, definitely won't) be as pretty as the recursive way, but it'll work.

Comment: As a note, that would just emulate recursion. Most people would consider something like that still recursive, as the approach itself is still recursive.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote an example which does the same with integer numbers: [Get all combinations for arbitrary number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248326/get-all-combinations-for-arbitrary-number-of-elements/60249211#60249211)

You can simply replace `int[]` by `String[]` there.

A complete interactive example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{

    /**
     * Return all possible combination of n Strings
     * @param n Number of parts to combine in each row
     * @param set Array of Strings to combine
     */
    static List<String[]> getAll(int n, String[] set)
    {
        List<String[]> combinations = new ArrayList<>();

        // First step (0)
        // Create initial combinations, filled with the first String.
        for (int number = 0; number < set.length; number++)
        {
            String[] array = new String[n]; // the final size of each array is already known
            array[0] = set[number]; // fill the first Part
            combinations.add(array);
        }

        // In each following step, we add one number to each combination
        for (int step = 1; step < n; step++)
        {
            // Backup the size because we do not want to process
            // the new items that are added by the following loop itself.
            int size = combinations.size();

            // Add one number to the existing combinations
            for (int combination = 0; combination < size; combination++)
            {
                // Add one part to the existing array
                String[] array = combinations.get(combination);
                array[step] = set[0];

                // For all additional Strings, create a copy of the array
                for (int number = 1; number < set.length; number++)
                {
                    String[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
                    copy[step] = set[number];
                    combinations.add(copy);
                }
            }
        }

        return combinations;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter some Strings, delimited by space");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String line=in.nextLine();
        String[] set=line.split("\\s+");

        // Calculate all possible combinations
        List<String[]> combinations = getAll(set.length, set);

        // Print the result
        for (String[] combination : combinations)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combination));
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Enter some Strings, delimited by space
aa bb cc
[aa, aa, aa]
[bb, aa, aa]
[cc, aa, aa]
[aa, bb, aa]
[aa, cc, aa]
[bb, bb, aa]
[bb, cc, aa]
[cc, bb, aa]
[cc, cc, aa]
[aa, aa, bb]
[aa, aa, cc]
[bb, aa, bb]
[bb, aa, cc]
[cc, aa, bb]
[cc, aa, cc]
[aa, bb, bb]
[aa, bb, cc]
[aa, cc, bb]
[aa, cc, cc]
[bb, bb, bb]
[bb, bb, cc]
[bb, cc, bb]
[bb, cc, cc]
[cc, bb, bb]
[cc, bb, cc]
[cc, cc, bb]
[cc, cc, cc]
```

To change the output format, you may use:

```
        // Print the result
        for (String[] combination : combinations)
        {
            String s=String.join("",combination); // Concatenate the parts of each combination
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

The the output format is:

```
aaaaaa
bbaaaa
ccaaaa
aabbaa
...
```

Please take a look at the linked topic to find the explanation how it works.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but here the number of strings in the array is now known in advance. I mean it is a parameter that changes from run to run. So I can not use a hardcoded `n` `for` loops as you have in your code.

Comment: You can of course fill the input parameters dynamically. There is no need to have them hard coded. This is just a simple example which focuses on the algorithm rather than on input ad output.

Comment: You read in your input file become you pass it to the getAll method. By that time you should know the length.

Comment: I asked for all the combinations where each word appears only once...
But thank you for the way of thought

Comment: "where each word appears only once" I missed that requirement. In this case you add a filter to the loop "for (int combination...." which prevents the wrong entries.